# Getting stray fetch request to JSON files while running getStaticProps/ getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, http-status-code-404

My page is working correctly, but When I look in the console I'm getting 5, 404 errors on fetch request. not sure where this is coming from..

I only get these 404s in production. Nothing in development.

[Page File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BhmL.png)

live site: https://real-fake-store.vercel.app/

github repo: https://github.com/Haviles04/real-fake-store

Here is the code I think it's coming from.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { products } = await import("../../../data/products/allData.json");
  return {
    paths: products.map((item) => {
      const productId = item.id;
      const productName = item.title
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/\s/g, "")
        .toString();
      const catName = item.category.name.toLowerCase().toString();
      return {
        params: {
          catName,
          productId: `${productId}=${productName}`,
        },
      };
    }),
    fallback:false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { categoryItems } = await import(
    `../../../data/products/${params.catName}Data.json`
  );
  
  const pageProduct = categoryItems.find(
    (item) => item.id === parseInt(params.productId)
  );

  return {
    props: {
      pageProduct,
    },
  };
}
```

and I'm getting [this in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVbDf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding passHref to the LINK component that was directing to the page.